# FTP live streaming for iPhone

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, objective-c, c++11

I want to prepare an iPhone app. A live stream will be coming for a moving camera (assume as a portable webcam) and I need to stream that live video to iPhone using FTP (assume we don't have internet in that area).

Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: You do know that FTP uses Internet, _right_?

Comment: How could your iPhone possibly receive data without the Internet? What you want is impossible.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining a camera that uses FTP

Comment: Wi-Fi / WLAN, no *Internet* needed. :)

Comment: Then why would he specify that he has no Interwebs?

Answer (score 7):

The question is a good one, often asked by programmers world-wide. How to stream via the internet with no internet connection.

The accepted answer is using swallows. The airspeed velocity of a swallow is well-known among technical groups. Basically, what you do is package up your information, append the bytes to the swallow, and send it on its way. **Beware**. You'll need a lot of swallows.

Of course, the **bandwith** will depend on whether it's an African or European swallow, but let's not go there.

Comment: They actually did this once in South Africa, by attaching USB sticks to messenger pigeons, and it was faster than the awful Interwebs they had there.

Comment: What about a fully laden swallow?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers